# Адрес ссылки

Tags: html, php

Здравствуйте! Что означает: #mce_temp_url#" mce_href перед ссылкой? И почему при нажатии на ссылку не происходит переход? Я меняюсь ссылками и мне нужно, чтобы переходили на мой сайт. Такая ссылка индексируется? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`#mce_temp_url#`** - это название якоря, с помощью которого визуальный редактор TinyMCE запоминает место, в которое необходимо будет вставить ссылку после ее настройки и создания.
Таким образом, при правильной работе скриптов, этот текст появляться не должен.

Так что ничего оно не означает, да и переходить-то некуда...)

Comment: Я меняюсь ссылками и мне нужно, чтобы переходили на мой сайт. Такая ссылка индексируется?

Comment: Если нет перехода - нет и индексации. А вообще, это ошибка наполнения, связанная, скорее всего, с неверной настройкой\установкой редактора. Чаще всего встречается в криворуких cms типа "joomla".

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очнеь помогли!